# What is the difference between “Must-do” and “Should-do”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

There was the following sentence in the article under the caption “Find your happiness “in iVillage. com.: http://www.ivillage.com/what-learn-annoyingly-happy-people/4-b-479266#ixzz2PiSjFoXw

> “If there are two words that are keys to contentment, they are
>   ‘limits’ and ‘boundaries,’” says Reiss. “Prioritizing **the must-do
>   items** on our lists is essential, after which **the should-do list** must
>   be narrowed down with polite but firm no-can-do responses.”

It seems the “must-do” things should be prioritized to “should-do” things in making  decisions. Is “Must” an order you must obey, and “should” is a mere recommendation that you can always or easily neglect?

What is the basic difference of “must-do” from “should-do” in terms of the level of obligation, moral and motivational aspects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *must-do* is an unavoidable requirement; a *should-do* is no more than a desirable goal.

Comment: Very succinctly put. I was trying to think of something to add which might help the OP more, but this says it all.

Comment: That's one of the basic differences. There are actually two factors involved. First, this is for **deontic** modals only; epistemic modality works differently. Second, whereas _must_ and its paraphrase _have to_ are "strong obligation" modals, _should_ and _ought to_ are said to be "weak obligation". And one big source of a distinction between what you have to do and what you should do is outside versus inside motivation for the obligation. That's where the _desire_ in a desirable goal comes from. Whereas obligation is almost always externally supplied.

Answer (score 4):

The [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), specifies how *must* and *should* should be interpreted in other Request for Comments' (RFC), which are technical specifications.

> 1.MUST   This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the    definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.

> 3.SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there    may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>   carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

You can interpret *must* and *should* in the same way for non-technical documents too.

Answer (score 1):

*Must do* implies necessity or inevitability and is a firm imperative or obligation, while *should do* implies subjective desire or an optimal outcome.